# jsoup send cookie with domain and path

Tags: java, jsoup, httpcookie

I can't solve howto send cookie via jsoup connect with domain and path.
Now I do this:

`Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(5000)).cookie("myCookie", "value").get();`

How to add domain and path for cookie?

Answer (score -2):

You should use a `Map<String, String> cookies` to store all necessary cookies and pass this map into Jsoup connection via `cookies(Map<String, String> cookies)` method:

```
Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(5000)).cookies(cookies).get();
```

Comment: But howto add domain and path there?